# "solved in two different ways" or "solved by two different ways"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, passive-voice

I have two different methods to solve a problem, and I intend to specify this in a passive sentence by using the word *verb*.

> This problem can be solved in two different ways.
>
> This problem can be solved by two different ways.

Which one is more correct?

I think the second one is more conventional.

Answer (score 3):

Using "Solved by" expects a description of the method or the person who can solve it.

> This problem can be solved by *using Pythagoras’ theorem*.
>
> This problem can be solved by a 5-year-old

If you are not describing the method "solved in" is better

> This problem can be solved in 2 ways
>
> This problem can be solved in 5 minutes

Comment: Never thought about this one before, but it seems not only can it be solved 'by named methods' it can also be solved 'by numbered methods'. "This problem can be solved by two different methods"  works for me; 'in' doesn't. Though I'd prefer 'using' or 'via', 'by' doesn't seem too bad.

Answer (score 1):

> This problem can be solved **by two different ways**.

In this sentence, it sounds like the problem can be solved by the ways themselves as though they were animated objects that were physically capable of doing such things as solving problems. Compare it with the following sentence:

> This problem can be solved **by John**.

A more fluent way to say it would be one with no prepositions at all:

> This problem can be solved **two different ways**.

You can think of the phrase *two different ways* as some sort of adverbial that describes the way the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

This problem can be solved using two different methods
Or

There are two approaches to solving this problem...